# Why won't Vue 3 rerender an <img>, even when it rerenders everything else in a component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm working on a Vue project, in which multiple link cards (`<a class='card'></a>`) are stacked inside a "deck" (`<div class='deck'></div>`). The setup for these is mostly pretty simple:

```js
<script setup>
const { cardData } = defineProps({
    cardData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
});
</script>

<template>
    <RouterLink class="card" :to="`/read/?id=${cardData.content_id}&v=${cardData.content_version}`">
        <CardImage :imageData="cardData" />
        <div class="card__text">
            <h3 v-html="cardData.content_title"></h3>
            <p>{{ cardData.content_snippet }}</p>
            <div v-if="cardSize == 'small__card'" class="card__details">
                <p>Word Count: {{ cardData.content_words }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </RouterLink>
</template>
```

When you click on one of these cards, chances are the next page will also have a number of cards on it — so let's say you're on one page with cards A, B, and C, and you click on C, and you're taken to a page with cards C1, C2, C3... and so on. For the most part, this works fine! All the data in the card will update.

*Except* the image. Nothing I have done has made the image update appropriately, even when I've set it up to work basically the exact same way this does.

The image does require some asynchronous setup, as I want to make sure that an image for the card exists before trying to render it. This is what I've got at the moment:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const { imageData } = defineProps({
    imageData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,

    }
});

const imgUrl = ref('');

async function checkIfImageExists(pathID) {
    let path = `/img/story/contents/${pathID}.webp`;
    const response = await fetch(path);
    if (response.status === 200) {
        imgUrl.value = path;
    } else {
        imgUrl.value = `/img/story/contents/000000.gif`;
    }
}

onMounted(async () => {
    await checkIfImageExists(imageData.content_id);
});
</script>


<template>
    <img :src="imgUrl" :alt="imageData.content_id">
</template>
```

And this works perfectly... *once*. On the first page, I'll get cards A, B, and C, all with the appropriate image... but then those images won't update. If I move to page C, I'll see cards with the *text* for C1, C2, and C3, but with images for A, B, and C, respectively.

Is there something I'm missing here? I'm pretty new to Vue, but I've spent days absorbed in tutorials, and feel like I've got a decent grasp of the basic. I've also spent hours perusing the Stack Overflow answers to similar questions, but I can't find anyone with this exact problem, so I haven't been able to find an exact solution.

The CardImage wasn't originally its own component, but I moved it to one in the hopes that it could handle the asynchronous fetch better in isolation. And as I mentioned, it does work *once*, but then never again. Watching for route changes doesn't do the trick either, even though that's what triggers the rest of the card data to change.

**Edit:** Might be worth noting that this problem only applies to "new" cards. If page one has A, B, C, and D, and then I see images for A, B, and C on cards for C1, C2, and C3, when I navigate *back* to page one, D *will* have the correct image, as it doesn't have one carried over from last time. This leads me to believe it's some kind of caching issue, but I have no idea how to override it. Adding a key to the image doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an alt image in Vue with `@error` directive and there's no need to check if the image exists with a separate function:

```js
<img :src="imgUrl" @error="$event.target.src='/img/story/contents/000000.gif'"/>
```

Alternatively, if you still want to do it there's no need to call `onMounted` hook here, you could have created a self-calling function instead. e.g.

```js
(function () {
  // logic
})();

// OR
const f = () => {
  // logic
}

f();
```

**EDIT**: Your code could be simplified to

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
    cardData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
});
</script>

<template>
    <RouterLink class="card" :to="`/read/?id=${cardData.content_id}&v=${cardData.content_version}`">
        <!-- Passing the image directly -->
        <CardImage :imageData="cardData.content_id" />
        <!-- Rest of the code -->
    </RouterLink>
</template>
```

Your `CardImage` component

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
    imageData: {
        type: string,
        required: true,
    }
});
</script>

<template>
    <img :src="`/img/story/contents/${imageData}.webp`" :alt="imageData" @error="$event.target.src='/img/story/contents/000000.gif'">
</template>
```

or simply

```
<RouterLink ...>
   <img :src="`/img/story/contents/${cardData.content_id}.webp`" :alt="cardData.content_id" @error="$event.target.src='/img/story/contents/000000.gif'">
   <!-- Rest of the code -->
</RouterLink>
```

Force reload a component, there are many ways to do it, and one of them is by using the `:key` method:

```
<RouterLink class="card" :to="`/read/?id=${cardData.content_id}&v=${cardData.content_version}`">
   <!-- Passing the image directly -->
   <CardImage :imageData="cardData.content_id" :key="cardData.content_id" />
   <!-- Rest of the code -->
</RouterLink>
```

Comment: That is helpful, but I'm still facing the same issue where the previous image at the same index will be carried over to the new card, even when it should be replaced with a new image. Strangely, the alt text (which is just the ID of the card for testing purposes) *does* update — it's only the image source that doesn't.

Comment: Without further inspecting it is hard to help, but have you checked if there are any errors in the console, if there are none related to the image try logging the image object to the console. You can also use vue dev tools in your browser to inspect the object and see whether it has the correct data or not.

Comment: I have tried using console logging, but it hasn't told me much. If I set up a watcher for the route, the props, or anything else, it doesn't seem to register when the image should be updating — it only logs when new cards are generated.

Comment: In your `onMounted()` lifecycle hook try adding `console.log(imageData.content_id)` and check if the correct image name is logged to the console or not

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried. If a new card is generated, it'll log the correct image URL, and set the image correctly. But if this is a card that's in the same position as a previous card, it won't log anything, even though the text on that card is updating correctly. Nothing I do can seem to make the image recognize that it should be re-rendered.

Comment: It means your component isn't being remounted, which makes sense if all you're doing is updating prop values.  For a component to mount again, it must first unmount, usually from the UI changing to where the component is completely removed from the screen. Move your function out of `onMounted` and into a watcher, watching the change in props

Comment: You'll also need to **not** destructure `defineProps`.  That causes the props in your `<script>` code to lose reactivity.  Assign to a variable, e.g. `props = defineProps({...})` and then your prop is available in your script as `props.imageData`

Comment: Are the props non-reactive as currently defined in my code? I've tried applying watchers to them, which haven't worked. Could that be why?

Comment: Also, is there a way I can force Vue to unmount and re-render the cards each time?

Comment: as @yoduh pointed out you should not destructure your props you can use `const props = defineProps({...})` or simply `defineProps({...})` and it does the gig. To force re-render there are many ways to achieve it and one of them is by updating the `:key`. Checkout updated answer for the instructions

Comment: props dont need to be assigned to anything in order to use them in your template code, as long as they're defined they'll just work.  It only matters when you're trying to use props in the rest of your script code.

Comment: "there's no need to call onMounted hook here" - there's a need because the hook is conventional, SSR-friendly place to do async side effects that is capable to handle the errors from promises. IIFE isn't.